# Using like query to get the desired output across two tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Hi all i am trying to achieve below query to return result from two table based on the condition given.How to put correct query to achive the expected  output?

```
SELECT * FROM  bw_tempclientdetails  
where companyname like '%fff%'  
not in (SELECT * FROM bw_clientallocation where companyname like '%fff%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) <--follow the link

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  bw_tempclientdetails bw_temp
  LEFT JOIN bw_clientallocation bw_client
    ON bw_temp.companyname = bw_client.companyname  -- this is just an identifier or link between the tables
 WHERE bw_client.company LIKE '%fff%'
   AND (bw_temp.companyname LIKE '%fff%' AND bw_client.company LIKE '%fff%');
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM  bw_tempclientdetails  
where companyname like '%fff%' and companyname   
not in (SELECT companyname FROM bw_clientallocation where companyname like '%fff%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from (
SELECT * FROM  bw_tempclientdetails  
where companyname like '%fff%' ) as t1
left join (SELECT * FROM bw_clientallocation where companyname like '%fff%') as t2
on t1.companyname = t2.companyname
where t2.companyname is null
```